# Numbered URL in CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, redirect, header

I am making a new website and I want the URL to be both in `numbered form as well as simple text form (just like stackoverflow.com 's URLS)` but I am unable to do so without calling headers as I want that whenever the user visits using url like

```
http://MY_WEBSITE/654321
```

then it goes to, say the page is linked to `abcd` then the URL should be like

```
http://MY_WEBSITE/654321/abcd
```

But here both `abcd` and `654321` are dynamic as they will change across links.

So, how should I do this? How to change to to new URL without `header`

Any suggestions of implementing in a `new way` or fixing the problem is heartily welcomed!

Comment: [Look at this](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: [Or this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13414796/3585500)

Answer (score 0):

This provides you for retrieving information from your URI strings

```
$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc
```

**example URL:**

```
http://test.com/index.php/controller/action/1stsegment/2ndsegment
```

then it shows!

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
$this->uri->segment(2); // action
$this->uri->segment(3); // 1stsegment
$this->uri->segment(4); // 2ndsegment
```